# launching my android app shows error log cat is not helping?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am a beginner. whenever I try to start my android app it shows an error `unfortunately my app has been stopped` . now let me be specific, I created a pushbots app for getting notifications and to show it on the textview by converting it into string. it works perfectly when a notification arrives, when I click on the notification it will show the strings on the screen, but not when I launch it . I asked a question for this before deadfish said that it could occur because my bundles are null so I did what I could to provide a temporary string for the textview on which I am displaying the string. But its still showing an error . I'll show you the logcat when I launch my app. and I think null bundle is not the problem

```
08-16 08:58:06.868  13447-13454/com.bluestacks.chartapp I/jdwp﹕ Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
```

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();


    //log the message in JSON format
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message >> " + intent.getExtras().toString());
    //Retrieve message and extra
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    if(message!=null) {
        t1.setText(message);
    }
    else
    {
        t1.setText("null");
    }

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String bigText = null;
    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("bigText")) {
        bigText = extras.getString("bigText");
        t2.setText(bigText);
    }
    else{
        t2.setText("null");
    }

}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Post a complete stack trace from logcat when your application crashes.

Comment: String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message"); intent can be null make sure to check if intent not null before trying to get extra

Answer (score 1):

Your `bunde` is `null` so your app will force close at this line:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Received message >> " + intent.getExtras().toString());
```

try this:

```
String message = null;

  //log the message in JSON format
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message >> " + intent.getExtras());
    //Retrieve message and extra
    message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    if(message!=null) {
        t1.setText(message);
    }
    else
    {
        t1.setText("null");
    }
```

Comment: that worked fine ... one more question (-.-)/ damn !!!! what r u guys ?? programming gods ????

Comment: Nope, just the same guy like you sometime ago :)